# Why do we see discrete light spikes coming out from a light source?

Tags: visible-light

[image: light sources]

When we look at a light source from a distance in suitable darkness, why do we see discrete light spikes coming out of source like Fig. b of above picture instead of Fig. a?

Comment: [Do you mean spikes like this](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/9597/what-does-a-hexagonal-sun-tell-us-about-the-camera-lens-sensor)? If so, your question is addressed in [How does Fraunhofer diffraction depend on the orientation of the sides of a lens?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/how-does-fraunhofer-diffraction-depend-on-the-orientation-of-the-sides-of-a-lens).

Comment: Who is this "we" you speak of?  I don't see that unless my glasses are dirty.

Comment: Perhaps more direct than Johns link is: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35935/what-are-these-rays-that-appear-in-photograph-of-sun?lq=1

Answer (score -1):

Your cristaline is not a lense made of homogeneous glass, it is made of cells. These are mostly transparent, but still there is a difference at their borders, and theses are aligned at large scale, forming a structure. This structure makes a slight variation of the optical properties, but it does diffract a bit of the incomming light, and at huge intensity you can see the resulting pattern.

It is even more intense at night when you see a bright spot, since your iris is then more widely open (exposing more of the structure).